# How to add dynamic value to dynamically generated inputs when typing?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a small application that allow users to write test exam questions and multiple choice answers. I'm trying to capture each choice option value as user types and append that value to the radio button. So if user inputs "red" in the first input, the first radio box input value should be "red".

For fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/a2s1t7b3/3/

This is what I have so far.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var numberofchoices = '<br><label for="inputEmail">Number of Choices</label>\n\
<input id="noc" required="required" placeholder="Enter number of choices" type="text" value="" class="form-control">';

  $('#nop').html(numberofchoices);


  $(document).on('keyup', '#noc', function() {
    var numberofchoices = $('#noc').val();
    var i = 0;
    var len = numberofchoices;
    var alphabetUpperCase = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

    if ($('#answers_choices').html() !== '') {
      $('#answers_choices').html('');
      $('#answers_correct_choices').html('');
      $('#select_question_answer').hide();
    }

    if (numberofchoices !== '') {

      for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {

        if (numberofchoices >= 1 && numberofchoices <= 26) {
          $('#answers_choices').append('<br><label> Option ' + alphabetUpperCase[i - 1] + '</label><input id="choice' + alphabetUpperCase[i - 1] + '" required="required" name="answer_choices" placeholder="Enter choice ' + alphabetUpperCase[i - 1] + '" type="text" value="" class="form-control">')
        }

        //radio boxes answers
        var radiobox = '<input id="answerchoice' + alphabetUpperCase[i - 1] + '" type="radio" name="multiple_choice_single_answer" value="">' + alphabetUpperCase[i - 1] + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';

        if (numberofchoices >= 1 && numberofchoices <= 26) {
          $('#select_question_answer').show();
          $('#answers_correct_choices').append(radiobox);
        }

        $(document).on('keyup', '#choice' + alphabetUpperCase[i - 1], function() {

          //alert('#choice'+alphabetUpperCase[i-1]);
          $('#answerchoice' + alphabetUpperCase[i - 1]).val($(this).val());

        });
      }

    }

  });




});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="nop"></div>
<div class="form-group" id="answers_choices"></div>
<label id="select_question_answer" style="display: none;">Select Question Answer(s)</label>
<div class="form-group" id="answers_correct_choices"></div>
```

Comment: this: _$(document).on('keyup', '#choice'_ where is the element on the page with the `id` of `choice`?

Comment: Look the line `if (numberofchoices >= 1 && numberofchoices <= 26) {` You will see that input with the id of choice being generated there.

Comment: What I see is the generated `id` containing the string 'choice' concatenated with the value of `alphabetUpperCase[i - 1] `. That _is not_ 'choice'.

Comment: Besides, my question came after looking at the generated HTML in the DOM inspector of the dev tools in the browser.

Comment: @RandyCasburn: I'm not sure I'm following because I can see it... What do you mean?

Comment: Define _it_ explicitly please. What do you see?  When I enter 3 for `Number of Choices`, the three Options have `id` values of `choiceA`, `choiceB`, and `choiceC`. I can find no where in the generated HTML where an `id` of `choice` exists.

Comment: @RandyCasburn : this is what I see in the inspector : https://pasteboard.co/HYjfIj9.png You see `id='choiceA'`, `id='choiceB'`, etc...

Comment: @RandyCasburn : Yes we both see same thing that's good. So what I'm trying to do is to capture the value when they enter value in choiceA, choiceB etc this should do it yes? `$(document).on('keyup', '#choice' + alphabetUpperCase[i - 1], function() {`

Comment: @RandyCasburn: so "if you enter "red"  in `id=choiceA`, the value of the radiobox with `id=answerchoiceA` should be "red" etc..

Comment: got it...brain dead I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for delay...got called away.

You've created a race condition with your handler. This is due to the reference to the variable `i` being reused and resulting in the same value being assigned to every event handler object. (number of choices + 1).

One approach to work around this is to use a closure that will preserve the value of `i` during each iteration:

```
  (function(i) {
      $(document).on('keyup', '#choice' + alphabetUpperCase[i - 1], function() {
        alert('#choice'+alphabetUpperCase[i-1]);
        $('#answerchoice' + alphabetUpperCase[i - 1]).val($(this).val());
      });
  })(i);
```

But there are several other optional solutions that would require restructuring your code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new function in a loop that is referencing a variable that is in an outer scope. The jsfiddle explains this by annotating the 'keyup' event binding with a yellow dot and underline.

[image]

Instead, you want to create a function that is bound to the character from the current iteration of the loop:

```
var getHandler = function(char) {
  return function() {
    //alert('#choice'+char);
    $('#answerchoice' + char).val($(this).val());
  };        
}
$(document).on('keyup', '#choice' + alphabetUpperCase[i - 1], getHandler(alphabetUpperCase[i - 1]))
```

Alternatively, you could bind a single handler (outside the loop) for all #choice[...]'s and store data against the choice to resolve it's corresponding #answerchoice:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input[name=answer_choices]', function() {
  const char = $(this).attr('id').replace("choice", "")
  $('#answerchoice' + char).val($(this).val());
})
```